# Access 2016 formula

Tags: ms-access-2016

Learning Access recently but find myself suck on a particular formula.
I've been trying to find a way to calculate the number of years since a employee's hire date and a specific date in place of today. 
I searched and tried a few Datediff and DATEDIF with no luck just get negative results if any. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it isn't that easy and there are some traps, indeed if you wish to count correctly taking leap years into account.

The trick is to always use *DateAdd* as in this function:

```
Public Function Years( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased step wise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2007-06-22. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a full 12 months period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -intYears, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of years as count of full 12 months periods.
  Years = intYears - intDiff

End Function
```

Typical usage:

```
HiredYears = Years([HireDate], #12/31/2017#)
```

Note, that for someone hired at the 1st of a month, a full year of employment will be counted at the next 1st of that month, so the expression may rather be:

```
HiredYears = Years([HireDate], #1/1/2018#)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried the datediff("yyyy",[Hiredate],12/312017) but get negative three digit number. I switch it around and get positive number but still three digits. I have to find the time in years between the date hired and 12/31/2017 as today's date.

Comment: _12/312017_ is not a valid date. And why do you run with _DateDiff_ when it can't do the job? That's why I posted the function. See edit for usage.